# Css se sigue descargando en web aunque ya el html no lo solicita

Tags: html, css, nginx

Administro una web en la que unos css ya no se necesitaban, por ende los quitamos. O sea, quitamos sus solicitudes `<link>`.

El tema es que en los ordenadores que he probado (uno que no es mio, o sea, uno que jamas ha solicitado la web que mantengo) se siguen descargando los css aunque en el html no se soliciten.

No entiendo que puede estar pasando. Y el servidor `nginx` que los sirve es un contenedor docker cuyo cache se borra con cada despligue, asi que por ese lado no es.

La pagina en cuestion es esta:

[groupinghotels](https://secure.groupinghotels.com/search?packageId=1)

Vean si en los css que se descargan archivos styles-*.min.css que no estan siendo referenciados en el html.

Gracias desde ya

[EDIT]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[EDIT 2]

Bueno, si voy al inspector pestania networks veo al hacer click en el initiator, el html donde se hace referencia.

Ahora, voy a  pestania elements, donde supongo que esta el html que se sirve, busco el mismo codigo y no existe.
No entiendo nada, o algo se me escapa

Comment: Esa descarga del css antiguo ¿te está generando algún problema? si es así, agrega mas detalles, porque no veo cómo se pueda ayudar con la información que entregas. Saludos

Comment: Mira el código fuente desde el navegador que estás accediendo y revisa que efectivamente no haya esos `<link>`

Comment: @AlterLagos edite la pregunta agregando el sitio en cuestion

Comment: @Bicho si, lo vi y no encuentr, puede ser tranquilamente un error mio

Comment: @AlterLagos es un problema de rendimiento, es un proyecto de riesgo en q cualquier descarga que no es necesaria, puede dejar al usuario con una experiencia pobre

Comment: Yo sí veo la descarga de los archivos y en el HTML están los `<link type="text/css" href="css/styles.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` o, por ejemplo, `<link ng-if="$root.whiteLabel === 'minube'" type="text/css" href="css/styles-minube.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`. Si usas la consola de depuración de Red podrás ver en la columna "iniciador" (chrome) en qué parte del código se solicita la hoja de estilos.

Comment: puedes creer que no veo el css que pida styles-minube.min.css?

pego una impresion de pantalla para que veas lo que veo en initiator

Comment: A tu pregunta **"Vean si en los css que se descargan archivos styles-*.min.css que no estan siendo referenciados en el html"** respondo: a mí solo se me descargan archivos CSS que están referenciados en el HTML.

Comment: Respondo a tu edición 2: Estás usando un marco de trabajo de javascript llamado **Angular.js** que, por si no lo sabías, manipula el DOM de la página para adaptarlo al estado de la aplicación. Es decir, puede que haya cosas que están en el HTML descargado que desaparezcan y puede que aparezcan nuevos elementos o que éstos se modifiquen. ¿Cuál fue el motivo de usar **angular.js** en tu web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nada. Era un problema con nginx, pero en la manera en la que entendia el despliegue en produccion vs el despliegue en local.

En produccion usamos contenedores, y ahi los assets estaban en otro path, y eso me habia mareado.

Gracias a todos